# How to Serialize data in MySQL without PHP

Tags: mysql, serialization

Is there anyway to INSERT serialized data in MySQL without php?

as example

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`data`) VALUES (SERIALIZED_DATA);
```

Comment: Need to insert some data which can unserialize using php. but can't insert these data using php as it has to be done by manually. As example I need to insert an data array as data.

Comment: What datatype is `data` column in `mytable`?

Comment: @peterm It's VARCHAR. It's possible INSERT php serialized data in VARCHAR column.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand the context of your question but if you have or can produce (e.g. on a separate box) and put your serialized data in a file then you can use [`LOAD_FILE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) to insert it  into the database

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`data`) VALUES(1, LOAD_FILE('/tmp/serialized.data'));
```